# Why those files are missing?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to add jQuery datepicker with `Zend_Form`. But it's giving two warnings and one error.
My sample code:

```
$startdate = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker( 'startdate' );
$startdate->setLabel('Start Date')
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->setAttrib('size', '10')
          ->setDecorators($formJQueryElements);
```

---

> Errors:
>   Warning: include_once(ZendX/JQuery/Form/Element/DatePicker.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

---

> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'ZendX/JQuery/Form/Element/DatePicker.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/students/application/../library:/opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/students/library:include_path = .:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/ZendFramework/library') in /usr/local/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

---

> Fatal error: Class 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/students/application/forms/Student.php on line 46

Comment: Can you post the code where you are including/ autoloading the ZendX library? Perhaps in your Bootstrap.php?

Answer (score 4):

ZendX is an extras library that is not included in all distributions of Zend Framework. Make sure you have downloaded from the [Zend Framework Download Page](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest) one of the distributions with *full* in the title.

After you extract the compressed files you will find the `ZendX` library in the folder `extras/library/ZendX` copy the `ZendX` folder to wherever you keep your current `Zend` folder (not in the Zend folder),

In my case I keep my Zend Framework Library at: `C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library`. So I would have 2 folders at this location `Zend` and `ZendX`.

`Zend` and `ZendX` both have default namespaces in the autoloader so if you store them in the same place, if one works the other will work.

Or... Put both in your application library like:

```
/application
/library
    /Zend
    /ZendX
```

This will work as well.

Comment: Thanks RockyFord, I added the two folders in the project's library folder, now there is no error. But I don't see any effect of datepicker in my application :(

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there I don't use that library.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some particular reason you're using ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker? I'm using the jquery datepicker (from the jquery ui package) with a normal Zend Form Text element like this..

```
    // Add start_date element
    $start_date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('start_date'); 
    $start_date->setLabel('Start Date')
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->setAttrib('class', 'datepicker')
          ->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);
    $this->addElement($start_date);
```

Adding the 'datepicker' class is all that's really required. This sidesteps the issue you are experiencing - which seems to be related to the use of the ZendX library.

Comment: could you please share the datapicker class

Comment: the datepicker class css comes with the jquery ui package. Go to http://jqueryui.com/ and download the whole package (you can build a lightweight custom package if you don't want all the UI elements). Install into appropriate folders on your web server. Add the links to the .js and .css files. Then add the Zend Form elements as above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know more about Zend framework, However, Zend Framework is Server side technology meant by PHP and Jquery is Client side Technology. In other word there is no direct relation between Jquery date picker working and Zend Framework.

You have to check the HTML output of your page including the form element that works with date picker and the Javascript include files in your page. just look to the page source in your browser, search for something missing.

Comment: "Zend Framework provides jQuery related View Helpers through its Extras Library." - [ZendX](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html)

Comment: Well, but finally, There is a boundary and connection between two entities Server side and Client side.

Comment: I am not getting any idea as I am very new to zend. Can you explain it little bit more to easily understand by a new comer. thanks

Comment: @user1559230 The main idea I mean is there is no direct relation between something occurs on the Server -Zend- and another thing occurs on the client -Jquery-. Indeed, the title of your question is meant by my question. I encourage you to check again your code and find why missing files are found. In most cases of missing files or paths issues, there is no someone can help the developer else himself.